# Format string is ignored after TextBox gets bound to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

In a dynamically built `UserControl` I have set the `format string` for a `TextBox` this way:

```
TextBox newTextBox = new TextBox();

TempViewModel viewModel = new TempViewModel();
var binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    Source = viewModel,
    Path = new PropertyPath("DecimalValue"),
    ConverterCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"),
    StringFormat = "{0:#,##0.00}"
};

newTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

public class TempViewModel
{
    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
}
```

That works fine so far.

But **after adding** a DependencyProperty the **format is ignored**. The `Dependencyproperty` is defined this way:

```
public class UserControl_CBOGridQuotePositions : UserControl
{

    private static readonly DependencyProperty Amount_QuotePos_Base_DependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Amount_QuotePos_Base", typeof(System.Decimal), typeof(UserControl_CBOGridQuotePositions), new PropertyMetadata(0m));

    public System.Decimal Amount_QuotePos_Base
    {
        get { return (System.Decimal)GetValue(UserControl_CBOGridQuotePositions.Amount_QuotePos_Base_DependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserControl_CBOGridQuotePositions.Amount_QuotePos_Base_DependencyProperty, value); }
    }

    private void MakeTheBindings(DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Amount_QuotePos_Base");
        binding.Source = this; // which is the UserControl_CBOGridQuotePositions

        newTextBox.SetBinding(dependencyProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

**Is there a way to make the format working while the TextBox is bound to a property?**

Comment: Because in MakeTheBindings you are replacing your Binding with a new one. Make sure when you do this  var binding = new Binding("Amount_QuotePos_Base"); that you also set all the properties such as ConverterCulture and StringFormat.

Comment: @Jon I tried that but still the same behaviour. In my original code the **format binding is set after the binding to the property**. So it should overwrite the property binding and perform the formatting.

Comment: @Jon, sorry, you are right. All I have to do ist to add                     `ConverterCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"),                     StringFormat = "{0:#,##0.00}"` in my `MakeTheBindings()`. I would accept this as answer. Many thanks!

Comment: glad that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in MakeTheBindings() you are replacing your Binding with a new one. Make sure when you do this var binding = new Binding("Amount_QuotePos_Base"); that you also set all the properties such as ConverterCulture and StringFormat